# Error during exponentiation: “math operation produced a non-number”

Tags: runtime-error, netlogo

during the execution of this code the model run in the error reported in the object. In a previous model where the variable land-sustainability was setting from 1 to 6  I
 didn't incurred in this kind of error. I listed the code below reporting  the portion of the code highlithed by the error at the end:

```
 turtles-own  [
 profit-from-fuel
 profit-from-food
 expected-fuel-sell-price
 expected-food-sell-price
 profit
 farm
 farm-size
   ]


patches-own  [
  fuel-yeld
  food-yeld
  land-sustainability
  water-level
  belongs-to
  food
  fuel

 ]

globals      [
  fuel-sell-price
  food-sell-price
  governs        
   ]


to setup        
 clear-all
 clear-all-plots
 create-farmers
 setup-land
 reset-ticks

  ask turtles
     [     set-farm-in-radius farm-size   ]

set fuel-sell-price 184 + random 55 + random -55 
set food-sell-price 184 + random 55 + random -55 

end


to create-farmers


create-turtles 30

[
 set shape "person farmer"
 setxy random-pxcor random-pycor 
 set profit-from-fuel  0  ; indicizzazione del profitto iniziale a 0
 set profit-from-food 0  ; indicizzazione del profitto iniziale a 0 

 set farm-size random 5 + 1
 set label farm-size
 ]
 end


 to setup-land

 ask patches [set belongs-to nobody]

 ask  patches
  [

   set pcolor 3
   set food-yeld 13000 
   set fuel-yeld 13000
   set land-sustainability random-float 0.9 + 0.1 ; per creare un moltiplicatore che     vada da 0.1  a 1
   set water-level random 3 * 1000
   if water-level = 0 [set water-level 1000]
    ]

  end


to set-farm-in-radius [d]
 move-to one-of patches with [not any? other patches in-radius d with [belongs-to !=     nobody]]
 set farm patches in-radius farm-size
 ask farm [set belongs-to myself]
 let c random 6 + 61
 ask farm [set pcolor c]
 end


to set-farm-distance [d]
  move-to one-of patches with [not any? other patches with [belongs-to != nobody and   distance myself < d]]
  set farm patches with [distance myself < d] 
  ask farm [set belongs-to myself]
  let c random 6 + 61
  ask farm [set pcolor c]
end



to go



ask turtles [

  set expected-fuel-sell-price fuel-sell-price + random 5 + random -5           
  if expected-fuel-sell-price < 0 [set expected-fuel-sell-price 1]
  set expected-food-sell-price food-sell-price  + random 5 + random -5
  if expected-food-sell-price < 0 [set expected-food-sell-price 1]
  set profit profit-from-fuel + profit-from-food
  if profit = 0 [ set profit 1 ]
  ]

 ask turtles [ 

  cultivate
   ask farm [recolor-farm]
      set profit profit-from-food + profit-from-fuel
    ]



  set fuel-sell-price fuel-sell-price + random 55 + random -55 
  if fuel-sell-price < 126 [set fuel-sell-price 126 ]
  if fuel-sell-price > 245 [set fuel-sell-price 245]                  ; è corretta come   assunzione? su un arco di 30 anni è ragionevole suppore che il limite massimo del prezzo    
  set food-sell-price food-sell-price + random 55 + random -55        ; sia di soli 5  euro più alto rispetto al massimo delgi ultimi 10 anni
  if food-sell-price < 126   [set food-sell-price 126]  
  if food-sell-price > 245 [set food-sell-price 245]

 if ticks =  Duration [ stop ] 
 if ticks > Duration [stop]

 ask patches 
 [ set food 0
   set fuel 0
   if land-sustainability  < 0.1 [set land-sustainability 0.1]        ; all'interno del  modello la land susitability varia in base alle colture utilizzate
   if land-sustainability > 1 [set land-sustainability 1 ]            ; ma questa non può comunque essere inferiore a 0.1 o maggiore di 1  
   ]

 tick

end

to cultivate
  let r risk-attitude 
  let e-f expected-fuel-sell-price
  let e-food expected-food-sell-price

  ask farm [
    ifelse land-sustainability < 0.35 or water-level < 1100           ; 0.35 è un valore arbitrario che può essere modificato vedere i documenti FAO
    [ ask myself [set profit-from-food sum  [food-sell-price * (((food-yeld  ) ^ (alfa)) * (((water-level) ^ (1 - gamma)) * ((land-sustainability) ^ (gamma))))] of farm 
      ]
    set food 2
    set fuel 0 
    set land-sustainability land-sustainability + 0.1   ; la scelta di coltivare prodotti destinati alla produzione di cibo incrementa il livello l-s del terreno così coltivato
    set pcolor 52.5
     ]

    [

     if land-sustainability >= 0.35 or water-level  = 0
     [

    let utility-from-food e-food * ((food-yeld  ) ^ (alfa)) * ((water-level) ^ (gamma)) * ((land-sustainability) ^ (beta))    ; da riscrivere la nuova formula con l'utilità di 
    let utility-from-fuel e-f *(( fuel-yeld) ^ (alfa)  * ((water-level) ^ (1 - gamma)  * (land-sustainability) ^ (gamma) ))


    ifelse utility-from-food < utility-from-fuel
    [
      ask myself [set profit-from-fuel sum [fuel-sell-price * (((fuel-yeld ) ^ (alfa)) * (((water-level) ^ (1 - gamma)) * ((land-sustainability) ^ (gamma))))] of farm ] ; ricominciare da qui cobb-douglas
      set fuel 1 
      set food 0
      set land-sustainability land-sustainability  - 1
    ]
    [ ask myself [set profit-from-food sum [food-sell-price * (((food-yeld ) ^ (alfa)) * (((water-level) ^ (1 - gamma)) * ((land-sustainability) ^ (gamma))))] of farm ]
      set food 1
      set fuel 0
      set land-sustainability land-sustainability + 0.5

    ]

  ]
]


  ]
  end

to recolor-farm
      if (food = 1 and fuel = 0 ) [set pcolor green ]
      if (fuel = 1 and food = 0 )[set pcolor yellow]
      if (fuel = 1 and food = 1) [set pcolor pink]       ; check
      if (fuel = 0 and food = 0) [set pcolor blue]       ; check
end
```

[ ask myself [set profit-from-food sum  [food-sell-price * (((food-yeld  ) ^ (alfa)) * (((water-level) ^ (1 - gamma)) * ((**land-sustainability) ^ (gamma)**)))] of farm

Answer (score 1):

`a ^ b` will produce this error message if `a` is negative and `b` is fractional, so for example if you try to take the square root of -1:

```
observer> show -1 ^ 0.5
ERROR: Runtime error: math operation produced a non-number
```

Trying adding `show land-sustainability` and `show gamma` before the `set profit-from-food ...` line, to see what the bad values are, exactly, that you're trying to exponentiate. Then you'll have some debugging to do to figure out where those bad values are coming from.
Probably you're letting `land-sustainability` become negative.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Now I'm wondering how to get mean of the variable "land-suitability" for each farm. I would like to put a plot or a monitor in the interface to display the mean of land-suitability. I've tried with a monitor with this function in the reporter -- mean [land-suitability] of turtles -- but I get the mean land-suitability only of the patches where the turtle is on, not of the all farm... How can I write a report for this purpose?

Comment: Seems unrelated. Ask a new question?